# How do parametric equations work?

Tags: conic-sections, parametric

[image: roughly drawn graph]

I was given a graph like this in my exam. Its defined para-metrically by x=c^2 and y =c^3. It won't help me now but could someone explain this to me why I have two seemingly different lines I know it is because its a parametric equation but I don't understand it in this context

Comment: If you have a parametric equation $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, it means that the coordinates on the $x$ axis are a function of the time, and the  coordinates on the $y$ axis are also a function of the time. Thus a usual function $y = f(x)$ could be represented as $\gamma(t) = (t, f(t))$. In your case, for the "function" $R$ you consider only positive values for $t$, hence $t^3 > 0$. For the "function" $S$, you consider the negative values of $t$, hence $t^3 < 0$, giving you the result you draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminating $C_i$ gives
$$x^3=y^2\qquad\blacksquare$$
There are two lines because the equation is equivalent to
$$x^3=(\pm y)^2$$
i.e. for each value of $x$ there are two possible values ($\pm$) of $y$.